# Sorting an object array in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an object array in AS3 and I would like to sort it based on their custom properties.

Is there an automatic way of sorting it or do I really have to define a function to do it?
Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
var records:Array = new Array(); 

records.push({name:"john", city:"montreal", zip:63144}); 
records.push({name:"bob", city:"toronto", zip:66345}); 
records.push({name:"bob", city:"vancouver", zip:16010}); 

records.sortOn(["name", "city"]); 

trace("records.sortOn('city', 'name');");
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the fast reply
It's doing what I want :D